# excel, calculating the variance of count data from groups of rows for groups of columns

Tags: excel, group-by, variance

I have an excel task I would like to perform where i look at count data for items (that come in more than one type). This count data is taken from individuals belonging to two groups. I would like to determine if there is a difference in variance between the groups for each of these item types based on the counts of the items' various versions (duplicates in this table)

The table would look like the following:

[image]

where, as columns, there are five individuals belonging to two distinct groups (A & B). As rows I have items. Items can come in more than one form (so the first row is item 1 variant-a, the second item 1 variant-b (but they are only labeled as the item type 'item 1' in the hopes of linking them together as a group in the table, the variant type doesnt matter so much). In the cells are counts of each item variant an individual from the two groups possesses. I would like to determine if the groups, A and B, have a difference in item type variance. So, does group A have a greater variance in the counts of item type 1 its individuals possess? Is there a difference in variance for item type 2 between groups and so on.

Is there a way to calculate this in excel?

Comment: For clarity, are the zero values (e.g. Ind3/GroupB, Item1 has 14 and 0) part of the variance calculation or are they truly treated as *null*? (i.e. Ind3/GroupB, has only 14 of Item 1) Also, which version of Excel (2013,16,19,365/Windows, Mac)?

Comment: I believe they would be treated as part of the variance, they are not unrecorded but rather represent the fact that the individual possessed none of the item...the item presence was tested for in all cases and a zero means there were 0 items present. And this would be done on a mac. Excel version 16.43.1

Comment: @Zoidberg_OuuuO I think it is possible. Can you please show your expected output manually so that we can do it by formula. Also please mention your excel version because `Excel-365` has some dynamic formula that can make easy to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your data are starting in A1 as follows:
[image]

**Excel 365 Method**

With Excel 365, you can normalize the data with this formula:

```
=LET( unPivMatrix, B2:F8,
      byMatrix, A2:A8,
   upC, COLUMNS( unPivMatrix ),
   byC, COLUMNS( byMatrix ),
   dmxR, MIN( ROWS( unPivMatrix ), ROWS( byMatrix ) ) - 1,
   upCells, dmxR * upC,
   upSeq, SEQUENCE( upCells,, 0 ),
   upHdr, INDEX( INDEX( unPivMatrix, 1, ),  1,  SEQUENCE( upC ) ),
   upBody, INDEX( unPivMatrix,  SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1,  SEQUENCE( 1, upC ) ),
   byBody, INDEX( byMatrix,  SEQUENCE( dmxR ) + 1,  SEQUENCE( 1, byC ) ),
   attr, INDEX( upHdr, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
   mux, INDEX( upBody, upSeq/upC + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
   demux, IFERROR( INDEX(
                         IFERROR( INDEX( byBody,
                                         IFERROR( INT( SEQUENCE( upCells, byC,0 )/byC/upC ) + 1, MOD( upSeq, upC ) + 1 ),
                                                  SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 1 ) ),
                                   attr ),
                         upSeq + 1, SEQUENCE( 1, byC + 2 ) ),
                    mux ),
   demux
 )
```

This formula takes in two variables: **unPivMatrix**, B2:F8 and **byMatrix**, A2:A8.  What you are doing is *Unpivoting the data in B2:F8 by the data in A2:A8*.

If you put that formula into cell H2, for example, then you end up with a clean, unpivoted table of data that spills into the cells below.  You can add headers to cells H1 (Item), I1 (Group), and J1 (Value) like this:

[image]

Now you have a pivotable table of data.  Select those data from H1:Jxxx and click **PivotTable** from the **Insert tab**.

[image]

Click OK on the Create Pivot Table window:

[image]

In the Pivot Table Fields window, arrange your fields like this:
[image]

In the values window, click the down arrow for **Sum of Value** and change it to Var or VarP as you prefer:

[image]

Now you have your results in a pivot table.

[image]

Where you can format and shape it to meet your needs.

**Excel 2016 Method**

If you have 2019 or lower, then I would recommend using PowerQuery to first unpivot your data by Group value and then publish a table into a worksheet that you can apply a Pivot to as above.  To illustrate that is time consuming, so I will not post it unless really necessary.